# Mimicking mathspec practices in LuaLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, luatex, unicode-math

After discovering the magic of `microtype`, I've decided to switch to `LuaLaTeX` from `XeLaTeX` for a large document. Unfortunately, I'm having some difficulties mimicking my `mathspec` practices from the prior engine; the desired font is Alegreya. Here's what I'm trying to fix:

1. Music accidentals (`$\flat \sharp \natural$`) should all be the standard Computer Modern glyphs. I clarify this because, as shown in the MWE, I'm also using the `lilyglyphs` package.
2. All superscript and subscript numbers should be Alegreya (with old-style numbers). This is easy enough with `amsmath`'s `\text` in math-mode, but I use it so often I'd like to make it the default.
3. Letters in math mode (`$x$`, for instance) should be Alegreya italic.

I've experimented with some `unicode-math` fixes, but I can't seem to get what I'm looking for.

MWE:

```
%LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya}
\usepackage{amsmath} %% \text in math mode

%\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmathfont[]{Alegreya} %% option range=0048-0057 ?

\let\origflat\flat %% this is included just in case; I use lilyglyphs but not its sharp, flat, or natural
\let\origsharp\sharp
\let\orignatural\natural
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\let\flat\origflat
\let\sharp\origsharp
\let\natural\orignatural

\begin{document}

$x$ and $y$ %% should be Alegreya italic

$\flat \sharp \natural$ % should all be standard CM

$^5_3$ %% should be Alegreya, old-style numbers

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To have the text font in math mode, you might want to use the [`mathastext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) package.  To use this package with LuaLaTeX you also have to load `fontspec` with the `no-math` option.  Because `fontspec` is loaded internally by `Alegreya` we do

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
```

Instead of saving and restoring the definitions of `\flat`, `\natural` and `\sharp`, we simply undefine them and redeclare them with their original mathcodes and the Computer Modern family.  We do so after loading `lilyglyphs`.

```
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\let\flat\undefined \let\natural\undefined \let\sharp\undefined
\DeclareMathSymbol\flat   \mathord{letters}{"5B}
\DeclareMathSymbol\natural\mathord{letters}{"5C}
\DeclareMathSymbol\sharp  \mathord{letters}{"5D}
```

Additionally, the `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is superfluous, as the `fontspec` package will switch to `TU` encoding anyway.  Also, `\usepackage{amsmath}` is not needed for the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\let\flat\undefined \let\natural\undefined \let\sharp\undefined
\DeclareMathSymbol\flat   \mathord{letters}{"5B}
\DeclareMathSymbol\natural\mathord{letters}{"5C}
\DeclareMathSymbol\sharp  \mathord{letters}{"5D}
\begin{document}

$x$ and $y$ % should be Alegreya italic

$\flat \sharp \natural$ % should all be standard CM

$^5_3$ % should be Alegreya, old-style numbers

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added in the `[italic]` option for `mathastext`, but this is terrific, thanks!